# What should I use to create an app like Buffer Pablo (demo inside)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I know Ruby on Rails and JavaScript (including jQuery) and I want to create a web app like Buffer Pablo ([watch this 30 seconds video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmlrZXgNib4)).

But I'm not really sure what tools, gem or JS library to use and I need suggestion for that.

The main feature that I'm going to build is going to have:

- user can select a background image (already inside the app)
- user can upload a photo of their own from their computer
- user can place the uploaded photo freely within the canvas and scale it
- user can add some texts, change the font and color of the text, scale and move the texts freely within the canvas
- and finally, user can save their artwork as JPG file

Please help and suggest the tools, gems or JS library that can help me.

Comment: Is any price ok or does it have to be free?

Comment: @Tom I'm looking for free ones if any. Do you know any?

Comment: None come to mind but idk if that was a requirement or not